# How to update data property value in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new in Vuejs & still not pretty clear about vue reactivity system. Here in the following code I am trying to update the initial value of a variable in data property using a method.

```
<script>
  name: "OrderDetails",
  data(){
    tax:5,
    subtotal:0
  },

  computed:{
    calculateSubtotal:()=> {
      let subtotal;

      -----some code--------

      this.subtotal = subtotal;
    }
  }
</script>
```

But still the subtotal remains 0. How can I Update the value ?
Here is the code snippet https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-borg-384rl?file=/src/App.vue

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Do you call/run/output that computed property anywhere? (Also, I think you should use a watcher instead or just return `subtotal` from your method) https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: My advice - if you are a newbie - follow the VUE docs (Great docs). For example you wont find any `arrow function` under the computed docs `calculateSubtotal:()=> {` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Vue.js docs are great, but the information regarding fat arrow/function is not straight forward. I can see how a beginner could easily miss this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code

1. You must not use fat arrow when declaring computed methods. `this` will not bind to your instance.

```
computed:{
  calculateSubtotal() {
      let subtotal;

      -----some code--------

   this.subtotal = subtotal;
  }
}
```

2. Your `computed` methods should not have side effects. This means that you must compute values based on `data` or external information, but **do not update data** from within the method. You should return the value you want.

```
computed:{
  calculateSubtotal() {
    let subtotal;

      -----some code--------

    return subtotal;
  }
}
```

3. If you never reference the `computed method` (call it) it will not execute. You're not calling `calculateSubtotal` anywhere and as such it is never run. You need to call it somewhere. In the template for instance.

```
{{{calculateSubtotal}}
```

Here's [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-mountain-nd3k2?file=/src/App.vue) with proper `this`, returning a value and calling the computed method. But you **shouldn't do this**. This bring me to no 4.

4. You should just use the computed method as any other data, and not pass it as params to other methods. This will work in `methods` also.

This is a complete [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-pasteur-n15ru?file=/src/App.vue)